# Your user profile is not associated with this service

Tags: security, customer-portal, portal

I've cloned a profile called Heathrow Portal which works fine when you want to log in onto the portal. But Now that I've created a profile for Atkins it comes up with the following error message : "Your user profile is not associated with this service. Contact your site administrator for more information" 

 
Does anyone know how to assosiacte a profile with this service ? I've put them on all security setting and profile are the same since it's cloned
[image]

Comment: Did you add that cloned profile to the list of profiles available for the community?

Comment: How do I add the profile to the list of profiles available for the community  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cloned a profile which is enabled for Community and created a profile from it, you need to manually add the newly created profile to Community.

Please add the newly created profile to the profiles enabled for Community in the Community detail page.